# In double slit diffraction, why does the intensity profile not change w.r.t. distance from the slit if is a collimating lens fixed in between them?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference, lenses

As far as I know, with respect to double slit interference, the distance $y_m$ measured along the screen from the central point to the *m*-th bright fringe is related to the distance $L$ from the slits to the screen by:

$$\tan_m(\Theta) = \frac{y_m}{L}$$

In the case I am talking about, **the collimating lens is a focal length away from the screen**, but I don't know how this means that the distance from the slit(s) no longer matters.

Answer (score 0):

the parallel lines from the slit are focused at distance  f from the lens. at the point where a line thru the middle of the lens would meet the wall
 the formula $\tan(\Theta)=y_m/L$ calculates the point where parallel lines meet.